# Writing results in to Extent Report via a method which is executed by multiple threads

Tags: java, spring-boot, executorservice, extentreports

I have a method which is executed in a multiple threads. The method performs an action then writes into result in to extent report.

```
public LinkedHashMap doSomething(){

// do something
....

extentReporObj.writeToReport(testName,result,..);
}
```

The above method is called inside the call method of a class which implements Callable

The problem I am having is multiple threads are trying to write in the report at the same time and it is throwing ConcurrentModificationException.

I have made the writeToReport method synchronized

```
public synchronized void writeToReport(String testName, String url, String request, String response, String resultStatus) {

    setTest(testName);
    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, testName + " Test Start");

    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "API URL  ::   " + url);

    if (request != null)
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "API Request  ::   " + request);

    if (resultStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("pass"))
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Status :: Pass");
    else
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Status :: Fail");

    if (null != response)
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "API Response ::   " + response);

    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, testName + " Test End");

    extent.endTest(test); 
}
```

The other thing is as testName is a global variable it is getting overridden by other thread before the the extent.endTest(test); line can be executed which gives me ExtentTestInterruptedException exception.

I searched a lot but all of them say synchronize the method but it's not working in my case.

Comment: If you're running tests in parallel you'll likely need to create threadlocal versions of your extent report objects.

Answer (score 0):

Like below,

```
public ThreadLocal<ExtentReports> extent = new ThreadLocal<>();

@BeforeSuite
public synchronized void setUp() throws IOException {
       extent.set(new ExtentReports());
       extent.get().attachReporter(htmlReporter);
}
```